# reload page before jquery function sets in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reload

i have Problems with my jquery file, which should toggle a navigation bar. But it only works if i reload the page. How can i implement that it will toggle everytime not only when the page got refreshed?

This is my jquery file

```
$(document).ready(() => {

 $('.projekte').on('click', () => {
 $('.nav-projekte').toggle();
 $('.nav-portfolio').hide();
 });

 $('.portfolio').on('click', () => {
 $('.nav-portfolio').toggle();
 $('.nav-projekte').hide();
 });
});
```

Comment: try $('body').hide();

Answer (score -1):

Change the hide from 'nav-projekte' and 'nav-portfolio' to toggle, when you use toggle, the action is different from show and hide triggers. The first toggle maybe'll show, and the next toggle'll hide.

Answer (score -1):

The `toggle()` method toggles between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

So if the element is hidden it will show it, and if the element is shown it will hide it.

i guess you wanted to do something like that:

```
 $(document).ready(() => {

   $('.projekte').on('click', () => {
     // $('.nav-projekte').show();
     // $('.nav-portfolio').hide();
     $('.nav-projekte').toggle();
     $('.nav-portfolio').toggle();
   });

   $('.portfolio').on('click', () => {
     // $('.nav-portfolio').show();
     // $('.nav-projekte').hide();
     $('.nav-portfolio').toggle();
     $('.nav-projekte').toggle();
   });
});
```

(in comments is the way to go without `toggle()`, just show and hide what u need when you press each element.)

but if you meant that the action is not bound to the elements, only upon refreshing the page, it might be because of `TurboLinks`.

You can try adding the `page:load` event instead of only using `document.ready()` function like in the example:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function(event) {
  // Your code goes here
});
```

Or you can remove turbo links from your rails app by doing the following:

1. remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` form the gem file.
2. remove the `//= require turbolinks` from your `application.js` file
3. in the file `application.html.erb` you need to remove `'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'` (or if you use rails 4 then remove `"data-turbolinks-track" => true`) from two lines in the file.

Comment: 1. yes, i think it is because of the turbolinks 2. i edited my file, but it is still the same when i start my local server, so the webpage doesnt recognize the edit. i implemented it simple with `<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>` you have an idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: @minennick i edited my answer, i think you should remove turbo links completely as i wrote. (unless you need it)

Comment: i dont know why, but at the moment nothing works :) sometimes i hate rails